# Finding average between many Oracle timestamps?

Tags: oracle, timestamp, average

So I am trying to find the average of a list of timestamps using Oracle. I have a table that grows for itemX. Each time itemX is called, it pushes a value into my table. This could be days, months, years of data and timestamps. What I am concerned with is only an average of the last 10 timestamps to come in, and only if they were in the last 3 hours.

I have data that looks like this...

```
ROW_NUM itemX   DEVICE_TIMESTAMP
1   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:46:51.000000 PM
2   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:45:50.000000 PM
3   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:44:49.000000 PM
4   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:43:49.000000 PM
5   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:42:49.000000 PM
6   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:41:48.000000 PM
7   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:40:47.000000 PM
8   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:39:46.000000 PM
9   9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:38:45.000000 PM
10  9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C    3/23/2020 12:37:44.000000 PM
```

Using:

```
select row_number() over(order by device_timestamp desc) row_num, 
                itemX, device_timestamp 
            from  tracks_report 
            where device_timestamp >= sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) - INTERVAL '03:00' HOUR TO MINUTE 
            and itemX = '9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C'
            order by device_timestamp desc
            FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

What I want to get is the average time between these 10 rows.. I have tried breaking this down to seconds and minutes, adding them dividing by 10 then averaging. But my values are not correct. This is going to be a function, where I can call it based on the itemX id.

Any suggestions? I should be getting something like 60 seconds. But my break down and average is only something around 47 seconds as a result.

Comment: What would an average of timestamps be? If there are only two, would that be the timestamp in the "middle", i.e. the one for which the absolute value of the intervals to both the two input timestamps are equal? What result do you expect with that sample data?

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a result in seconds. So, if each record is 61 seconds from the last record, then I'd be looking for 61. The data provided is pretty close, in real time there could be minute delays from one incoming record to the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `LAG`/`LEAD` analytic functions to find the previous/next value and then subtract to get an interval and extract the component parts and average:

```sql
SELECT itemx,
       AVG(
         EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM diff_since_last ) * 3600
       + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff_since_last ) * 60 
       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM diff_since_last )
       ) AS average_seconds_difference
FROM   (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY itemx ORDER BY device_timestamp DESC )
           AS rn,
         itemx,
         device_timestamp,
         device_timestamp
           - LEAD( device_timestamp )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY itemx ORDER BY device_timestamp DESC )
             AS diff_since_last
  FROM   tracks_report t
) t
WHERE  rn <= 10
AND    FROM_TZ( device_timestamp, 'UTC' ) >= SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3' HOUR
GROUP BY itemx
```

For the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tracks_report ( itemX, DEVICE_TIMESTAMP ) AS
SELECT 'A1',
        CAST( TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'HH' ) AS TIMESTAMP )
          + INTERVAL '1:01.000001' MINUTE TO SECOND * ( LEVEL - 1 )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ITEMX | AVERAGE_SECONDS_DIFFERENCE
> :---- | -------------------------:
> A1    |                  61.000001
> ```

*(Note: the average includes fractional seconds, which I assume is important since you are using `TIMESTAMP` data-types and not `DATE` data-types.)*

*(Note 2: This is averaging the intervals from the latest 10 timestamps to the preceding timestamp; so it will consider the interval from the 10th to 11th most recent timestamp, even if that 11th timestamp is outside the 3 hour range and the 10th is within 3 hours. If you want to only consider when the all values are within that 3 hour range then move the filter from the outer query to the inner query. And if you want to compare on the 9 intervals between the 10 values [rather than 10 intervals between 11 values] then change to `rn <= 9`.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca36ef1e0c74e1036ce524233ffabd8a)*

Comment: Thank you. I have been hitting my head against the wall, not considering lead. I appreciate the information. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Same basic idea as @MTO, but this uses your original query - including the filter/limit - in a CTE:

```
with cte1 (row_num, itemx, device_timestamp) as (
  select row_number() over(order by device_timestamp desc), 
    itemX,
    device_timestamp
  from tracks_report 
  where device_timestamp >= sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) - INTERVAL '03:00' HOUR TO MINUTE 
  and itemX = '9094E4E56CAEF8D7E0531965000A285C'
  order by device_timestamp desc
  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
)
select row_num,
  itemX,
  device_timestamp,
  device_timestamp
    - lead(device_timestamp) over (partition by itemX order by device_timestamp desc)
    as diff_interval
from cte1;
```

And you can then get the difference from the intervals in seconds with `extract()`:

```
with cte1 (row_num, itemx, device_timestamp) as (
...
),
cte2 (row_num, itemX, device_timestamp, diff_interval) as (
  select row_num,
    itemX,
    device_timestamp,
    device_timestamp
      - lead(device_timestamp) over (partition by itemX order by device_timestamp desc)
      as diff_interval
  from cte1
)
select row_num, itemX, device_timestamp, diff_interval,
  extract(hour from diff_interval) * 3600
    + extract(minute from diff_interval) * 60
    + extract(second from diff_interval) as diff_seconds
from cte2;
```

And instead of displaying them all, get the average:

```
with cte1 (row_num, itemx, device_timestamp) as (
...
),
cte2 (row_num, itemX, device_timestamp, diff_interval) as (
...
)
select avg(
    extract(hour from diff_interval) * 3600
      + extract(minute from diff_interval) * 60
      + extract(second from diff_interval)
  ) as avg_diff_seconds
from cte2;

AVG_DIFF_SECONDS
----------------
      60.7777778
```

The only reason I still posted this is that it behaves differently because of where the filter/limit is applied. This is looking at the average of the 9 intervals between the 10 most recent timestamps (if there are that many in the last 3 hours). If you apply the filter/limit at the end then it will include the interval between the 10th and 11th, even if the 11th is many hours earlier.

Which is right is up to you of course, it isn't entirely clear from the question.

Comment: @MTO - yes, but it depends if you want the average of 9 or 10 gaps. The 10th gap comes out as null, which avg ignores. With the OP's data there There are 7 gaps of 1:01 and two of 1:00, which is 547, which averages across those 9 as 60.777...  If the 11th record is much earlier the 10th gap could skew that a lot. Like I said, it's not clear quite what is required. (So I already upvoted your answer *8-)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll have to consider which would be more effective. The requirement was  from a non-tech person who randomly said grab the last ten timestamps and give me the average, only if they came in the last 3 hours. So, I will have to think about both. I don't think the "number of timestamps" matters as much as within the last 3 hours. but the greater the number, the larger the gap could be. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Ambiguous requirements are always fun *8-) I'd probably mock up some data that clearly demonstrates the difference - e.g. with small gaps between your 10 most recent values, and then a big gap to the 11th; run queries that show the gaps and both answers you could get; and ask the non-tech person which one makes more sense to them. <shrug>

Comment: That's a great idea. Again, thanks for the information.